# how can i have the first 3 elements of an array of variable length in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, splice

i would like to get the first 3 elements of an array of variable length. i've sorted my array and i would like to get a Top 3.

here's what i've done :

```
var diffSplice = this.users.length - 1;
return this.users.sort(this.triDec).splice(0,diffSplice)
```

my "solution" work only for an array of 4 element ( -1 )

Is there a better way to use the splice method ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you try [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)?

Comment: `top = arr.slice(0, 3);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for the first three items.

```
return this.users.sort(this.triDec).slice(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to use a const value for diffSplice like

```
var diffSplice = 3;
return this.users.sort(this.triDec).slice(0,diffSplice)
```

try running

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(arr.slice(0, 3));
```

refer to [Array Silce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score -1):

Fill out the deletecount for Splice:

```
var sortedArray = this.users.sort(this.triDec);
return sortedArray.splice(0, 3);
```

check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Why the downvote? For using `splice` instead of `slice`? OP didn't mention the original array should be maintained.